# Java code should execute every 5 seconds for one minute

Tags: java, timer, timertask

My requirement is my java code should execute for every 5 seconds until for one minute. My code should start running every 5 seconds after completion of 1 minute it should stop executing that means my code should execute 12 times and it should stop.
I tried with java util Timer and TimerTask with the help of this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jdk-timer-scheduler-example/)... but it dent satisfy my requirement it has the functionality just to execute every 5 seconds but it dosen't have the functionality to terminate execution after one minute...

Any suggestion will be helpful
Thanks You...

Comment: Show Your attempt. What requirement was not satisfied?

Comment: add your code to people help you....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a Runnable scheduled for repeated execution after a certain number of executions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269294/how-to-stop-a-runnable-scheduled-for-repeated-execution-after-a-certain-number-o)

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 1.5, ScheduledExecutorService was introduced and it's preferred to TimerTask. you can implement your requirement with it like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
    ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        //do what you want
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    executor.schedule(() -> schedule.cancel(false), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

as you can see scheduleAtFixedRate schedule your main task to run every 5 seconds with a fixed rate. if you want it to sleep 5 seconds between tasks, try to use scheduleWithFixedDelay. the second schedule just runs once after a minute to cancel the previous schedule.

EDIT:

to use in java prior to 1.8 just replace lambda section `()->{...}` with

```
new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is what I want but, I am using java 1.7. lamda expression dosent work for me.

Comment: you can replace lambda sections with Runnables, nothing changed

Comment: check my edit. note it's just an anonymous class. you can also create a class which extend Runnable and pass an instance of it

Comment: if you get the right answer mark my answer as correct